# Is there an equivalent to sessionStorage in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'd like to implement the equivalent to the javascript sessionStorage and localStorage in my React Native app.  I have localStorage sorted with the React Native AsyncStorage component. But I'm unsure how to replicate sessionStorage.  To function how I want it to, I would like the sessionStorage to be cleared every time the app closes.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Havent Heard of that, but if i absolutely had to clear storage when app is turned off , i would add useEffect cleanup function which would set AsyncStorage to null. I guess thats not really what you were asking, but maybe this hack might work.

Comment: What was the solution you chose?

Answer (score 3):

If your using typescript you could store this file somewhere in your project name it something like "Storage.tsx"

```
declare module globalThis {
    let sessionStorage: Storage;
}

class Storage {
    private data: Map<string, any>;

    constructor() {
        this.data = new Map<string, any>();
    }

    public key(n: number) {
        return [...this.data.keys()][n];
    }
    public getItem(key: string) {
        return this.data.get(key);
    }
    public get length() {
        return this.data.size;
    }

    public setItem(key: string, value: any) {
        this.data.set(key, value);
    }
    public removeItem(key: string) {
        this.data.delete(key);
    }
    public clear() {
        this.data = new Map<string, any>();
    }
    
}

let sessionStorage = globalThis.sessionStorage = globalThis.sessionStorage ?? new Storage();

export { Storage, sessionStorage };
```

If your using regular javascript store it as "Storage.jsx"

```
class Storage {
    constructor() {
        this.data = new Map();
    }

    key(n) {
        return [...this.data.keys()][n];
    }
    getItem(key) {
        return this.data.get(key);
    }
    get length() {
        return this.data.size;
    }

    setItem(key, value) {
        this.data.set(key, value);
    }
    removeItem(key) {
        this.data.delete(key);
    }
    clear() {
        this.data = new Map();
    }
    
}

let sessionStorage = globalThis.sessionStorage = globalThis.sessionStorage ?? new Storage();

export { Storage, sessionStorage };
```

I know this is an late answer but could work for other people stumbling on this post.

Comment: For iOS < 12.2, `globalThis` does not work. I got error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: globalThis`, but this works on iOS above 12.2 and works for Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can store things in a central state, using like `Context API` or `redux`. I think that would be the best alternate for session.